# Angular Upload control shows red after successful upload

Tags: .net, angular, kendo-ui, upload, asp.net-web-api2

I am looking to use the Upload control in Angular 5 in a very barebones way.  I don't need the interceptor to show progress.  I am only using the uploadevent:

```
<kendo-upload
     (upload)="uploadEventHandler($event)">
</kendo-upload>
```

To call the handler that then calls my backend api by populating formData with the files selected.  The upload succeeds.  But the control shows red instead of green.  It is not receiving my .NET response of 200 for some reason.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to the fact that kendo is also sending a request to the endpoint specified by [saveUrl], if none is specified it will still do a POST request to the base href.

**Solution 1**
Use the [saveUrl] to send the request

**Solution 2**
You can interrupt the request by preventing the default behavior of the UploadEvent:

```
uploadEventHandler(e: UploadEvent) {
 // your logic
 e.preventDefault()
}
```

**Solution 3** Set the saveMethod="GET", that way it will always to a GET request that will succeed.